# Why does blockchain.info say BTC was traded for $35?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate

According to blockchain.info, BTC reached a peak rate of $35 in June 2011. According to the data available from bitcoincharts.com, the highest price BTC was traded in Mtgox that month (and until recently, the all-time high) is $31.9099.

What is the reason for this discrepancy? Does blockchain.info give the rate from an exchange other than Mtgox?

Comment: Not sure but there were a lot of canceled trades occurring back in the day, especially with the fraudulent access to login credentials occurring before Mt. Gox realized there truly was a security breach.

Comment: @StephenGornick: Weren't these things some time after the peak?

Comment: Could you point to the page that says this?

Comment: @NickODell: http://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?timespan=all&showDataPoints=false&daysAverageString=1&show_header=true&scale=1. It's not so visible now, it can be found by searching for "35.0" in http://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?timespan=all&showDataPoints=false&daysAverageString=1&show_header=true&scale=1&format=json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past blockchain.info got their prices from two sources: MtGox and Tradehill (though in the meantime they have removed the reference to Tradehill from their description). It could be related to that.

Also other media report a peak rate of USD 33, e.g., http://www.economist.com/blogs/babbage/2011/10/virtual-currencies